# Time SQL data type generating Invalid Variant Exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net, sqldatatypes

My environment is as follows:

SQL Server 2008
Visual C# Express running on Windows 7

I have a stored proc which returns a number of fields, including one which is of data type 'Time'.  When i try to assign this field to a variable (in the code snippet have used timespan, which is apparently the one to use, but have also tried datetime and object with the same result) the compiler gives the following MDA error:

> InvalidVariant was detected
>   Invalid variant was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object.  Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss.

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

The code is as follows:

```
private void CreateCScrapeObjects(string ItemsToScrapeStoredProc, int MaxItemsPerRequest, int SendRequestTolerance)
    {
        object tempobjecttotestnull;
        string scrapename;
        string scrapeurl;
        string scrapetemplate;
        string latestflag;
        string parameter1;
        string parameter2;
        string parameter3;
        string parameter1replacestring;
        string parameter2replacestring;
        string parameter3replacestring;
        int dataitemsperday;
        DateTime lastsuccessfulrequesttime;
        DateTime lastscrapeddatadate;
        TimeSpan scrapetime;

        DateTime startdate;
        DateTime startdateforrequestitem;
        DateTime enddate;
        DateTime enddateforrequestitem;

        int latestdateoffset;
        string scrapefrequencytype;
        int scrapefrequencynumber;
        string rescrapefrequencytype;
        int rescrapefrequencynumber;


        Scrapeobject MyScrape = new Scrapeobject ();
        List<ADODB.Parameter> oParams = new List<ADODB.Parameter>();
        ADODB.Recordset oRst = new ADODB.Recordset();
        if (_databasequeue.RunStoredProcedure(ItemsToScrapeStoredProc, , oParams, _connectstring, ref oRst, ADODB.ExecuteOptionEnum.adOptionUnspecified))
        {
            while (!oRst.EOF)
            {
                scrapename = (string)oRst.Fields[0].Value;
                scrapeurl = (string)oRst.Fields[1].Value;
                scrapetemplate = (string)oRst.Fields[2].Value;
                latestflag = (string)oRst.Fields[3].Value;

                tempobjecttotestnull = oRst.Fields[5].Value;
                if (tempobjecttotestnull.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                { parameter1 = ""; }
                else
                { parameter1 = (string)tempobjecttotestnull; }

                tempobjecttotestnull = oRst.Fields[7].Value;
                if (tempobjecttotestnull.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                { parameter2 = ""; }
                else
                { parameter2 = (string)tempobjecttotestnull; }

                tempobjecttotestnull = oRst.Fields[9].Value;
                if (tempobjecttotestnull.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                { parameter3 = ""; }
                else
                { parameter3 = (string)tempobjecttotestnull; }

                tempobjecttotestnull = oRst.Fields[4].Value;
                if (tempobjecttotestnull.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                { parameter1replacestring = ""; }
                else
                { parameter1replacestring = (string)tempobjecttotestnull; }

                tempobjecttotestnull = oRst.Fields[6].Value;
                if (tempobjecttotestnull.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                { parameter2replacestring = ""; }
                else
                { parameter2replacestring = (string)tempobjecttotestnull; }

                tempobjecttotestnull = oRst.Fields[8].Value;
                if (tempobjecttotestnull.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                { parameter3replacestring = ""; }
                else
                { parameter3replacestring = (string)tempobjecttotestnull; }

                dataitemsperday = (int)oRst.Fields[14].Value;
                latestdateoffset = (int)oRst.Fields[15].Value;
                scrapefrequencytype = (string)oRst.Fields[10].Value;
                scrapefrequencynumber = (int)oRst.Fields[11].Value;
                rescrapefrequencytype = (string)oRst.Fields[12].Value;
                rescrapefrequencynumber = (int)oRst.Fields[13].Value;



                scrapetime = TimeSpan.Parse( Convert.ToString ( oRst.Fields[16].Value));
                lastsuccessfulrequesttime = Convert.ToDateTime(oRst.Fields[17].Value);
                lastscrapeddatadate = Convert.ToDateTime(oRst.Fields[18].Value);

                startdate = GetNextScrapeDate(scrapefrequencytype, scrapefrequencynumber, lastscrapeddatadate,scrapetime );
                enddate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(latestdateoffset);

                startdateforrequestitem = startdate;
                enddateforrequestitem = GetScrapeRequestEndDate(scrapefrequencytype,scrapefrequencynumber,lastscrapeddatadate,enddate,MaxNGCDataItemsPerRequest,scrapetime);

                while(startdateforrequestitem<enddate)
                {

                    if (MyScrape == null)
                    {
                        MyScrape = new ScrapeObject();
                        MyScrape .DefineScrape(startdateforrequestitem, enddateforrequestitem, scrapeurl, scrapetemplate);
                        MyScrape .AddItemToRequest(latestflag, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter1replacestring, parameter2replacestring, parameter3replacestring);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int expecteddataitems = ScrapeFrequency.ExpectedDataItems(scrapefrequencytype,scrapefrequencynumber,startdateforrequestitem,enddateforrequestitem,scrapetime);
                        if (expecteddataitems > MyScrape .MinRemainingScrapeItems(MaxItemsPerRequest ))
                        {
                            _scrapequeue.AddQueueItem(MyScrape );
                            MyScrape = null;
                            MyScrape = new ScrapeObject();
                            MyScrape .DefineScrape(startdateforrequestitem, enddateforrequestitem, scrapeurl, scrapetemplate);
                            MyScrape .AddItemToRequest(latestflag, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter1replacestring, parameter2replacestring, parameter3replacestring);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MyScrape .AddItemToRequest(latestflag, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter1replacestring, parameter2replacestring, parameter3replacestring);
                        }

                    }


                }
            }
            if (MyScrape != null)
            {
                _scrapequeue.AddQueueItem(MyScrape );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //raise error
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong version of adodb (i had been using an old com version because that was working and i didn't feel the need to reinvent the wheel).  Nonetheless, in this case I should have updated because the Time SQL datatype is new and (apparently) not supported by the older adodb versions.  I rewrote all the database interaction to use adodb.net and it works fine with the Timespan type.